# How to make two Theme.MaterialComponents.Dialog with same size?

Tags: android, material-components-android, appcompatactivity

I have an `AppCompatActivity` which starts another `AppCompatActivity` as a dialog by setting `theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Dialog"` in `manifest.xml`. This dialog is displayed nicely with margins on all sides.

The first dialog starts a second dialog with the same settings. But this dialog has margins on all sides as well but seems to have the first dialog as reference. So the second dialog is smaller then the first one but I want it to be the same size. Is this possible?

[image: Schematic overview of dialogs]

Manifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name=".activity.Dialog1"
    android:label="Custom"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Dialog"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    />
<activity android:name=".activity.Dialog2"
    android:label="Custom"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Dialog"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    />
```

Dialog1.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/dialog1_layout">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/add_poi_text"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="@string/add_poi_text"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Dialog2.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/poi_specific_layout">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/default_fields_placeholder">
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure anymore, since I forgot I asked this question, but I believe I solved it by passing a different activity/context. So instead of passing `Dialog1` I passed `AppCompatActivity` and used that as the context to start `Dialog2`.